# Kafka compacted topic does not remove null messages

Tags: apache-kafka

I have kafka compacted topic with cleanup.policy=compact,delete, and delete.retention.ms = 60000.
Anaywas, messages with value NULL under key still are on this topic and kafka dont want to remove them.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue ?

I want remove old messages and messages with with value null

Comment: There are different settings that can affect the log to be cleaned:
`min.compaction.lag.ms` it sets the minimum amount of time that a messages will live before being eligible for compaction. It gives consumers the time to read tombstone messages.


`min.cleanable.dirty.ratio` it's the ratio between clean and dirty segments. Only after the ratio is exceeded the log will be eligible for compaction.

Comment: Thank you :) also the setting  segment.bytes also was important